# Wordpress Image is not displayed as featured image nor in Gallery

Tags: wordpress, image, post, upload, gallery

I have a wordpress website set up. I've uploaded many images and most of them show up in the gallery. But some of them don't and they don't show up as featured images for posts when I select them from the gallery. 
The website is: http://www.radiebuk.at/wordpress/?p=320
As you can see no featured image is displayed for this post.

The image file link is:
http://www.radiebuk.at/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/calla_21.jpg

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: see single.php in your theme and put code here to show featured image

Comment: which code to show the featured image?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail